# Javascript Map Array Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have This simple array :

```
var gdpData = {"CA": 1,"US": 2,"BF": 3,"DE": 4};
```

I want to find the value of BF using a loop

how can I do this by loop using JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: do you need to loop?  you can just do `gdpData.BF`

Comment: If you use a loop for this anyone reviewing your code should either reject it or be fired.

Comment: I was not aware of this method of identification of object in javascript. honestly first time to see this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) and not an array.
You can just call:

```
gdpData.BF // -> returns 3
```

Comment: what kind of object is this ? Is there any documentation for this kind of objects available ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals

Comment: I have a function which has a variable named code.
code has value like "BF" but when I tried your method gdpData.code, undefined returned in my alert. you know why ?

Comment: use `gdpData[yourVar]`

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
var res = gdpData["BF"];
```

or

```
var res = gdpData.BF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the jquery each function

```
var gdpData = {"CA": 1,"US": 2,"BF": 3,"DE": 4};

jQuery.each(gdpData, function(key, value) {
    if(key == "BF") {
        alert(value)
    }
})
```

Comment: ...just because we can, doesn't mean, we should!

Comment: I think you(@nirazul) haven't properly understood the sentence "You can also use the jquery each function". Its clearly written 'also' in the sentence structure

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var key in gdpData){
 if(gdpData[key] == "BF") // do something ...
}
```

Note you have an object though, not an array. an object is more like a hashmap

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you CAN use your own personal loop, but there's really not point because javascript does the hard work for you.

```
var obj = { 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3 };
var res = obj['a'];
```

But if you REALLY want to use a loop for some weird reason...

```
function findValue (obj, item) {
    for (key in obj) {
        if (key === item) {
            return obj[key]; // OH LOOK - that's exactly the same thing.
        }
    }

    return undefined;
}

var obj = { 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3 };
var res = findValue(obj, 'a');
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
var gdpData = {"CA": 1,"US": 2,"BF": 3,"DE": 4};

for(var i in gdpData){
    if("BF" === i){
        alert(gdpData[i]);
    }
}
```

sorry for the 'var'

Comment: -1 for leaking a global and using `i` for a non-numeric loop variable

Comment: 'i' should be 'var i' otherwise your script will break